# Multinomial random generation with maximum size in each box

Tags: r, random, multinomial

In R, I would like to generate a multinomially distributed random number vector of a given size N, for example using `rmultinom`, but with a maximum size for each of the K boxes.
For example:

```
set.seed(1)
draw = rmultinom(n = 1, size = 1000, prob = c(67,211,264,166,144,52,2,175))
```

In this case, the size is `1000`, specifying the total number of objects that are put into eight boxes (the `length` of `prob`), and `prob = c(67,211,264,166,144,52,2,175)` the vector of probabilities for the eight boxes (which is internally normalized to sum 1). In addition, I would like `c(67,211,264,166,144,52,2,175)` to be the vector of the maximum size for each of the eight boxes.

However in this case, it is possible to generate numbers that are higher than `c(67,211,264,166,144,52,2,175)` (for instance in the example above, `draw[7,]=4` is higher than 2), whereas I would like each number to be lower or equal to the maximum size of each box specified in `prob`, in addition to `draw` summing to `size = 1000`.

Do you know any function or any simple way to do that? I was not able to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution): "For n *independent* trials each of which leads to a success for exactly one of k categories, with each category having a given fixed success probability, the multinomial distribution gives the probability of any particular combination of numbers of successes for the various categories".

The keyword here is *independent*.  Your constraint on the number of times each category can be drawn means the sampling is not independent.  If your problem were multinomial, it would be possible - though very unlikely - that all numbers could be drawn from box 7.  This is not what you want, so you can't use `rmultinom`.

Here's a different approach:

```
# vector of item counts
m <- c(67,211,264,166,144,52,2,175)
# expand the item counts in to a single vector with i repeated m[i] times
d <- unlist(lapply(1:length(m), function(x) rep(x, m[x])))
# sample from d without replacement
s <- sample(d, size=1000, replace=FALSE)
# count the number of items of each type were sampled
table(factor(s))

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
 63 197 242 153 135  48   2 160
```